# Node Promise returning the input parameter instead of my return value

Tags: node.js

I have this promise to get the twitter content from an ID

```
function get_twit_content(twit_id){
return new Promise(function(resolve){
    twitter_client.get('statuses/show/', {id: twit_id, tweet_mode : 'extended'}, function(error, tweet, response) {
        var twit_content;
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
            twit_content = false;
        }


            twit_content = tweet.full_text;

            return twit_content;
        });

        // resolve the promise with some value
        setTimeout(function() {
              resolve(twit_id);
            }, 1000);
})
```

}

```
var twit_content = get_twit_content(twit_id);
twit_content.then(function(twit_content){
        console.log(twit_content);}
```

this gives me the twit_id instead of the twit_content that I want

Answer (score 1):

Your promise resolves with whatever you have in its `resolve()`. The return you have in the callback only returns from the callback, without any effect. Instead of creating a timeout (very wrong approach), put `resolve(twit_content)` inside the callback and you're done.

```
function get_twit_content(twit_id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        twitter_client.get('statuses/show/', {id: twit_id, tweet_mode : 'extended'}, function(error, tweet, response) {
            var twit_content;
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
                twit_content = false;
            }
            twit_content = tweet.full_text;
            resolve(twit_content);
        });
    })
}

get_twit_content(123).then(twit_content => console.log(twit_content));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set return value for `Promise` with `resolve()`, if you want to set twit_content as return value, you have to call `resolve(twit_content)`

Answer (score 0):

The `twitter` client already returns a [`Promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter#promises), you don't need to create one yourself.

```
function get_twit_content(twit_id) {
    return twitter_client.get('statuses/show', {id: twit_id, tweet_mode: 'extended'})
        .then(function (tweet) {
            return tweet.full_text;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_twit_content(twit_id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        twitter_client.get('statuses/show/', {id: twit_id, tweet_mode : 'extended'}, 
        function(error, tweet, response) {

        if (error){
            console.error("Error Fetching Twitter...")
            reject(error) //or throw error
        }

        twit_content = tweet.full_text;

        resolve(twit_content);
    });
})

get_twit_content
    .then( response => console.log("Data Fetched", response))
    .catch( error => console.log("Check network and try again...")
```